# Wedge product of scalars

Tags: exterior-algebra

For scalars, s and t, is it true that s ^ t = t ^ s = st and s ^ s = t ^ t = 0?

Also, for a vector, v, is it true that s ^ v = v ^ s = sv?

Is there a proof in each case?

Comment: Wedging with a zero-form $f$ (i.e. a function), is just multiplication by $f$.

Comment: So is s ^ s = 0 incorrect?  Also,I am a little confused about the geometric algebra interpretation of e1e1e2e3 = e2e3 = e2 ^ e3 whereas e1e1e2e3 = e1 ^ e1 ^ e2 ^ e3 = 0 ^ e2 ^ e3 = 0 where e1, e2 and e3 are basis vectors.  This seems inconsistent.

Comment: Vectors and scalars are two different things. If $s$ is a scalar, $s\wedge s = s^2$. If $v$ is a vector $v\wedge v = 0$.

Comment: Makes sense.  Any thoughts on the second part?

Comment: As I said, wedging with a scalar or a function $s$ is multiplication by $s$, so $s\wedge v = sv$.

Comment: ok.  I think I may have it.  In GA uv = u.v + u ^ v.  Let u = (e1e1) and v = (e2e3) then (e1e1) = 1 so uv = 1.(e2e3) + 1 ^ e2 ^ e3.  But (e2e3) = 0 so e1e1e2e3 = e2 ^ e3.  Am I right?